# How can you align an element with the top of a table that is attached to the bottom of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to be in line with the top edge of a table. I would normally be able to just put both of them in a containing div, but the table is aligned with the bottom right of its parent. (To explain maybe a little better, I want the top of the blue and black boxes in the snippet below to be in line with each other.)

The reason why I want to do this is that with a lot of cells in the table, the table can only resize in jumps of several pixels due to several cells changing by 1 pixel. If there is a way to do this in some other way, that would work too.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#myTable {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

td {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#myDiv {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I imagine that there will probably be some sort of css thing to do this, but I haven't been able to find it. Sorry if this is really simple, I'm pretty new to css.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options that might work depending on your scenario:

1. Make `#myDiv` a child of the `<td>`.
2. If you know the height of the `<td>` and it will always be at the bottom of the `<table>`, you can align `#myDiv` to the bottom of the table (possibly with some kind of offset) instead.

Other than those, I don't think you can do this with CSS. You might be stuck using JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question poorly. I want to align the div with the top of the table, not the <td>. I don't know if that changes anything, but that is what I meant.